# Need help in Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, post

I have this code to `POST` value to main.php, with onclick function UserID will be called and value which is user_id should be changed based on selected value and load selected `user_id` in `user_profile.php?ID=user_id`

```
var USER_ID = 0;
function UserID(user_id)
{
USER_ID = user_id;
              $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: "main.php",
                  data: {ID: USER_ID},
                  success: function(msg)
                  {
                    alert(USER_ID);
                    $('#user_profile_content').load('user_profile.php?ID=USER_ID #user_profile_content');
                  },
                  error: function()
                  {
                      alert("error");
                  }
              });
}
```

After success post, alert is showing with selected value, it means `POST` was successful but I don't know how to make `user_profile.php?ID=USER_ID` to be changed based on received value. It's not replace global variable `USER_ID`.

Comment: so in main.php you return something ?

Comment: Please post the snippet of the returned values in the ajax

Comment: Check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa). It seems related.

Comment: show us the code for the main.php

Comment: Use a descriptive headline.  "Need Help" applies to _every question on SO_

Comment: @AmrAly , i edited the code, please check

Comment: if you want to access `USER_ID` inside your `success` block you can do some [string interpolation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) like so: `$('#user_profile_content').load('user_profile.php?ID=${USER_ID} #user_profile_content');`

Comment: @AmrAly not worked,in this case it works only                 `$('#user_profile_content').load('user_profile.php?ID='+USER_ID);` but don't know how to replace #user_profile_content

Comment: @Sara you're right i should have replaced the `` with the ''.

Comment: @AmrAly there is another thing,how can i make php variable of returned value?

Comment: I am afraid i don't understand your question could you please be specific on what you want to achieve

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you want to change the url route, try:

```
...
success: function(msg){
    window.location.href = `user_profile.php?${msg.id}`
    $('#user_profile_content').load(`user_profile.php?ID=${msg.id}
#user_profile_content`);
...
```

1. ES6 template literals allow you to insert the returned value in a string.
2. `Window.location.href` allows you to change the route on the browser (Frontend), I recommend you do it from the Backend if possible though.
3. This answer assumes `msg.id` is the desired value that you want to pass since the contents of the response are not specified.

Comment: in this case                     `$('#user_profile_content').load('user_profile.php?ID='+USER_ID);` works only,but don't know how to load `#user_profile_content` instead the first one